# change gitolite from manual installation to package

Tags: git, gitolite

I want to change my manually installed gitolite to the package installation, because it's easier to updates.

How can I do that, without loosing my repositories? / How can I backup my repositories, before I start playing around with gitolite installations?

Thanks,
Flo

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository/2129286#2129286)** to backup each of your git repo.

Otherwise, upgrading a gitolite installation is as simple as pulling the gitolite git repo and replaying the `install` script.
You can see an example in my [gitolite installation script](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh), which I can replay over and over the same gitolite installation: it will upgrade it each time.